anthropic.AuthenticationError: Error code: 401 invalid x-api-key
I had an issue accessing the Anthropic API. It was giving me 401 error.
anthropic.AuthenticationError: Error code: 401 - {'type': 'error', 'error': {'type': 'authentication_error', 'message': 'invalid x-api-key'}}

I generated a fresh API KEY, and it didn't work either.

Running the following code block in a Python Notebook gave me a detailed message about the error. Then, I realized that I needed to add credits or payment methods. After loading some credits using a credit card, it started working 
import os
from anthropic import Anthropic
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load the .env file
load_dotenv()

client = Anthropic(
    # This is the default and can be omitted
    api_key=os.environ.get("ANTHROPIC_API_KEY"),
)

message = client.messages.create(
    max_tokens=1024,
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Hello, Claude",
        }
    ],
    model="claude-3-opus-20240229",
)
print(message.content)

Error message without credits
BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'type': 'error', 'error': {'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'message': 'Your credit balance is too low to access the Anthropic API. Please go to Plans & Billing to upgrade or purchase credits.'}}

